# Laravel Excel not working in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-excel

I recently just got stuck with this problem. Exporting my database data to excel using Laravel Excel. I just copied the code on the tutorial links, but unfortunately it doesn't work on me. And I think I got everything setted up for laravel excel configuration.Can you help me solve this? Thanks. Here are my codes.

**my controller method**

```
public function exportInventory(){

    $products = Product::all();

    Excel::create('products', function($excel) use($products){

    $excel->sheet('Excel sheet', function($sheet) use($products){

      $sheet->fromArray($products);
      $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');

    });

    })->export('xls');

}
```

**My Model**

```
<?php

 namespace App\Product;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Product extends Model
 {

//
   protected $fillable =   ['pharmaceutical','description','unit','quantity','price','amount','type','packaging','lot','expiry_date_month'];
   protected $guarded = ['price'];
 }
```

**My Database Table**

[image]

**Error**
[image]

Comment: And which one is line 76 in your ProductController ?

Comment: it points out the })->export('xls');

Comment: Please help me with this...

Answer (score 1):

Change your code :
$products = Product::all(); to
$products = Product::all()->toArray();

Comment: Did it helped you?